# Maximum value of trigonometric equation $\cos^2(\cos\theta) + \sin^2(\sin\theta)$

Tags: trigonometry

**For any real $\theta$ the maximum value of** **$$\cos^2(\cos\theta) + \sin^2(\sin\theta)$$**

**A. $1$**

**B. $1 + \sin^21$**

**C. $1 + \cos^21$**

**D. does not exist**

I tried it by converting the whole expression into $\sin$ but getting nowhere with that.

$$1-\sin^2(\cos\theta) + \sin^2(\sin\theta)$$

Now since 1 is constant therefore, **$$[\sin^2(\cos\theta) + \sin^2(\sin\theta)]$$** should be minimum but I don't know how to minimize it.

Also is there a way to think about it's solution graph.

I have to solve this without using calculus.
Kindly help.

Comment: Graphing the equation I got that B. is the maximum.

Answer (score 9):

$$\max_{\theta\in\mathbb{R}}\{\cos^2(\cos\theta) + \sin^2(\sin\theta)\}\le\max_{-1\le x \le 1}\cos^2 x+\max_{-1\le y \le 1}\sin^2 y=1+\sin^21$$

$$\cos^2 \left( \cos \frac{\pi}{2} \right) + \sin^2 \left( \sin \frac{\pi}{2} \right) = 1 + \sin^2 1$$

So, the maximum is at most $1+\sin^21$, and this value is achieved. Hence the answer is **b)**.

Comment: +1 Sorry I ran out of votes. :( Your answer is inspirational.

Answer (score 8):

Hint:

1) $f(x):=\cos^2(\cos\theta) + \sin^2(\sin\theta)$ is a periodic continuous function of period $\pi$.

2) $f(x)=f(\pi-x)$.

3) $f$ is increasing in $[0,\pi/2]$ because $\cos^2(\cos\theta)$ and $\sin^2(\sin\theta)$ are increasing in $[0,\pi/2]$.

4) $f$ attains its maximum at $\pi/2$ and $f(\pi/2)=1+\sin^2(1)$.

Answer (score 6):

The idea is that we can maximize the argument of $\sin^2$ while also maximizing $\cos^2\theta$. To do so, we know that $\cos\theta$ (and $\cos^2\theta$) is maximized when $\color{red}{\theta = 0}$ and $\sin\theta$ is maximized when $\color{blue}{\theta = \pi/2}$, hence our result. We only need to notice that $\sin^2$ is increasing on $[0, 1]$ (remembering the graph of $\sin$ helps here) to conclude we have the max:

$$
\cos^2(\color{red}{\cos \pi/2}) + \sin^2(\sin \color{blue}{\pi/2}) = \cos^2(0) + \sin^2 1 = 1 + \sin^2 1.
$$

So the correct answer is $(b)$.

Comment: I like your answer because at every $\pi/2$ the maximum occurs when I graphed it.

Comment: Dude you confused the letters. The answer you got is B. and wrote down C. please edit your post.

Comment: @Sigma6RPU nice catch.

Comment: Your welcome I was like wait right answer wrong letter.

Answer (score 0):

I thought about the problem like this when I saw the graph.

> $$\cos^2(\cos\theta) + \sin^2(\sin\theta)$$
>   $$\cos^2(\sin(\frac{\pi}{2}-\theta)) + \sin^2(\sin\theta)$$
>   $$\sin(\theta+\frac{\pi}{2})=0$$
>   $$\sin(\theta+\frac{\pi}{2})=\sin(\pi)$$
>   $$\theta+\frac{\pi}{2}=\pi$$
>   $$\theta=\frac{\pi}{2}$$

I used the co-function identity between $\sin(\theta)$, and $\cos(\theta)$. In case anybody wonders where I got the $\pi$ that is the period of the $\sin^2(x)$, and $\cos^2(x)$.  $\pi$ maximizes cosine and minimizes sine.

Comment: I'm not sure about your line where you claim $\sin(\theta + \pi/2) = \sin \pi$. This isn't true if $\theta = 0$, for instance.

Comment: @AOrtiz I set $\sin(\theta+\frac{\pi}2)=0$ You are right but just to point out one solution I set it to sine of $\pi$